# RoR: what should I add to my routes file to get rid of this error: No route matches [POST] "/users/1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, form-helpers

I have an application where a user can make microposts. But enter one into the form and press post, it says No route matches [POST] "/users/1". I don't understand this. It sounds like it is trying to create a /users/1 or the first user, but I am simply using a form to create a micropost. Here is my current routes.rb file ...

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :comments

    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
  resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy] do
    resources :comments

  end
  resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'


  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
```

and this is the output when I run rake routes:

```
user_comments GET    /users/:user_id/comments(.:format)                    comments#index
                       POST   /users/:user_id/comments(.:format)                    comments#create
      new_user_comment GET    /users/:user_id/comments/new(.:format)                comments#new
     edit_user_comment GET    /users/:user_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format)           comments#edit
          user_comment GET    /users/:user_id/comments/:id(.:format)                comments#show
                       PUT    /users/:user_id/comments/:id(.:format)                comments#update
                       DELETE /users/:user_id/comments/:id(.:format)                comments#destroy
        following_user GET    /users/:id/following(.:format)                        users#following
        followers_user GET    /users/:id/followers(.:format)                        users#followers
                 users GET    /users(.:format)                                      users#index
                       POST   /users(.:format)                                      users#create
              new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                                  users#new
             edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                             users#edit
                  user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                                  users#show
                       PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                                  users#update
                       DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                                  users#destroy
              sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                                   sessions#create
           new_session GET    /sessions/new(.:format)                               sessions#new
               session DELETE /sessions/:id(.:format)                               sessions#destroy
    micropost_comments GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                       POST   /microposts/:micropost_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     micropost_comment GET    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                       PUT    /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                       DELETE /microposts/:micropost_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            microposts POST   /microposts(.:format)                                 microposts#create
             micropost DELETE /microposts/:id(.:format)                             microposts#destroy
         relationships POST   /relationships(.:format)                              relationships#create
          relationship DELETE /relationships/:id(.:format)                          relationships#destroy
                  root        /                                                     static_pages#home
                signup        /signup(.:format)                                     users#new
                signin        /signin(.:format)                                     sessions#new
               signout DELETE /signout(.:format)                                    sessions#destroy
                  help        /help(.:format)                                       static_pages#help
                 about        /about(.:format)                                      static_pages#about
               contact        /contact(.:format)                                    static_pages#contact
```

I guess what I really need is for [POST] users/:id to route to microposts#create, but I don't know the syntax for it.

p.s. If I add post "users/:id", :controller => "users/update", I get the error:

```
ArgumentError (missing :action):
  config/routes.rb:4:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
  config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

here is the form which is talking to the controller (i think)

```
<%= form_for :micropost do |f| %>

  <div class="field no-indent">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "What's something else you want to buy?" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'micropost[kind]', "purchase" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

also, here is the microposts_controller.rb

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(params[:micropost])
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def new
    @micropost = Micropost.new(params[:micropost])
  end

  def show

    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = Micropost.where(:user_id => @user.id)
    @purchases = @microposts.where(:kind => "purchase")
    @sales = @microposts.where(:kind => "sale")


  end
```

and the users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, 
                only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :following, :followers]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save
      sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you want "[POST] users/:id to route to microposts#create," ? Basically, post against users/:id shouldn't do anything in rails. POST is to create a new object. So if you want to create a new micropost, it should be a post request against microposts/. Could you post your user and micropost controllers?

Comment: well Im not sure that I do. All I know is that Its when I create a micropost with the post form that I get that error (no route for [post] "/users/1. I just wanna get rid of that error and make sure that when I create the micropost it updates the users show page to include it. I will post the user and micropost controllers too though

Comment: The form for the micropost, what view is it in?

Comment: its a partial under views/shared

Comment: but which view is using that partial? Also, your form_for is unusual and should probably look like: `form_for(@micropost) do` instead. It is alright to modify an existing example, but you might have modified a little more than what is needed.

Comment: its for the users#show view. And I used to have (@micropost) but I changed it to :micropost because I was getting errors telling me that @micropost was nil

Comment: @BigBoy1337 okay that certainly explains things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is multifold, as per the comments:

1) Revert the `form_for` to what it was before

2) Set the `@micropost` variable in the respective actions that are rendering that form. In the case of users#show, that would be the show action in `UsersController`

```
def show
  @micropost = Micropost.new
end
```

Comment: you were very helpful in fixing my error so I picked your answer but now I have new problem with the posts showing up that you can see at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502697/ror-why-arent-my-microposts-showing-up