# RoR: why aren't my microposts showing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Here is the users show view where they are supposed to show up. ..

edit (I have updated this post slightly you can see it at [RoR: How can I get my microposts to show up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520635/ror-how-can-i-get-my-microposts-to-show-up))

```
<section>
  <div id= "purchases">
    <%= render 'shared/micropost_form_purchase' %>
  </div>
  <div id="sales">
    <%= render 'shared/micropost_form_sale' %>
  </div>
</section>

<div id="purchases list">
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @purchases unless @purchases.nil? %>
  </ol>
</div>

<div id="sales list">
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @sales unless @sales.nil? %>
  </ol>
</div>
```

so the forms (partials) are loading fine, but then when I make a post, in either one, neither the purchases list nor the sales list shows up. I checked the database and they are being created along with an entry in the column indicating kind (either sale or purchase)

Here are the forms:

```
<%= form_for (@micropost) do |f| %>

  <div class="field no-indent">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "What's something else you want to buy?" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'micropost[kind]', "purchase" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

and

```
<%= form_for (@micropost) do |f| %>

  <div class="field no-indent">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "What's something else you want to buy?" %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag 'micropost[kind]', "sale" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

also, here is the show part of the users_controller.rb

```
 def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @micropost=Micropost.new
    @microposts = @user.microposts.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end
```

and here is the show part of the microposts_controller.rb

```
def show

    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:id])
    @microposts = Micropost.where(:user_id => @user.id)
    @purchases = @microposts.where(:kind => "purchase")
    @sales = @microposts.where(:kind => "sale")

  end
```

can anyone help me out? anything else i need? hmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just to be sure you are getting the results you want, you should try something like this in your view

```
<%= @sales %>
```

This should be a hash of the results you want. Then, if that looks good, you want to do something like this

```
<div id="sales_list">
  <ol class="microposts">
    <% if @sales.any? %>
      <% @sales.each do |sale| %>
        <li><%= sale %></li>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </ol>
</div>
```

And repeat for purchases

Comment: what if just <%= @sales %> doesn't show up? What does that mean?

Comment: That means that in your controller, when you set `@sales = @microposts.where(:kind => "sale")`, that query is not returning any results. So I would go into the console and check out your @microposts variable, and see what's going on with that.

Comment: do you know how I can define @microposts to be the collection of all microposts

Comment: Well, to get all the microposts, do `@microposts = Micropost.all`, but if what you want is all the microposts that belong to a certain user, you should create a has_many belongs_to relationship. Check out the [rails guides on associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for the basics, and I definitely recommend working through the rails tutorial by Michael Hartl until you have a good grasp on it.

Comment: I do have a has many belongs to relationship. each user has_many microposts and each micropost belongs_to a user. Do you know how I can alter @microposts = Micropost.all to indicate that I only want Microposts that belong to a certain user vs every micropost that has ever been created?

Comment: additionally, I have rewritten the question with your advice in mind at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520635/ror-how-can-i-get-my-microposts-to-show-up